# Javascript addition not working out

Tags: javascript

I just want to convert feet to inches for my little project, but it doesn't seem to work. All it is doing is adding the finally number to the end of the first number. I must be doing something wrong. I just want to multiply the first number and then add inches to that number. Thank you

```
            <!doctype>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Are you tall enough</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function ride(){
                var rideMin = 64;

                var ht = document.getElementById("height").value;

                if( ht >= 64){
                    alert("You may go on the ride!!");
                }else{
                    alert("Sorry, you may not go on the ride");
                }
            }

            function converter(){

            var aa = document.getElementById("feet").value;
            var bb = document.getElementById("inches").value;

            var cc = (aa * 12);

            var resu = bb+cc;


            document.getElementById("results").value = resu;

            }



            </script>
            <style>

            .container{
                width: 960px;
            }

            input{

                width:250px;
                height: 150px;
                margin-left: 375px;
            }

            img{
                margin-left: 300px;
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 40%;
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }

            h1{
                margin-left: 200px;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
                color: blue;
            }

            .conversion{
                margin: 0;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
            }

            .convert{
                margin-left: 390px;
            }

            .results{
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
                margin-left: 438px;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
            }
            </style>

            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="container">
            <h1> Are you tall enough to ride the roller coaster</h1>
            <img src="roller.png">
            <div class="convert">
            <h3>Convert feet to inches</h3>
            <input class="conversion" type="text" id="feet" placeholder="Enter feet here">
            <input class="conversion" type="text" id="inches" placeholder="Enter inches here">
            <input class="conversion" type="submit" onclick="converter()">
            </div>
            <div class="result">
            <input id="results" type="text" readonly>
            <div class="height">
            <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Please enter your height in inches please">
            <input type="submit" value="sumbit" onclick=ride()>
            </div>






            </div>






            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Input values are always strings. `"2" + "3"` (or even `"2" + 3`) is concatenation, not addition. Use `parseInt(bb)`, `parseFloat(bb)`, or `+bb` as appropriate. (I'll see if I can find a duplicate.)

Comment: Ah, the devilry of loosely-typed languages. I much prefer finding mistakes at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt to convert to integers:

```
 function converter(){

            var aa = parseInt(document.getElementById("feet").value, 10);
            var bb = parseInt(document.getElementById("inches").value, 10);

            var cc = (aa * 12);

            var resu = bb+cc;


            document.getElementById("results").value = resu;

  }
```

Comment: I suggest you do `parseInt(val, 10)` to make sure you get the correct results.

Comment: Thank you very much. This may be a stupid question but what does the 10 do? Could I just do parseInt?

Comment: @user2684242 It forces `parseInt` to treat the input string as base 10. The spec says the base-system "is assumed to be `10` except when the number begins with the character pairs `0x` or `0X`, in which case... `16` is assumed." Compare `parseInt("0xFF")` and `parseInt("0xFF", 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
function ride(){
                var rideMin = 64;

                var ht = document.getElementById("height").value;

                if( parseInt(ht) >= 64){
                    alert("You may go on the ride!!");
                }else{
                    alert("Sorry, you may not go on the ride");
                }
            }

            function converter(){

            var aa = parseFloat(document.getElementById("feet").value);
            var bb = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inches").value);

            var cc = (aa * 12);

            var resu = bb+cc;


            document.getElementById("results").value = resu;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `parseInt`, you can use an addition sign to coerce the string to an integer.

```
var aa = +document.getElementById("feet").value;
var bb = +document.getElementById("inches").value;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cdVM/2/).